# add variable string to img src path on click

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to set a variable inside and image path using jQuery on click. The models function below sets the folder variable which will be the folder name inside the image path. So example of button 1 is clicked i want the variable 'folder' to be set to 'folder1', so that when i click a colour it takes the the image form that folder. My problem is that when i choose a colour the variable is not passed into the path and the right path assign to the image src.

jquery...

```
var folder = '';

//MODELS


$(function() {
 $('.folder1').click(function(){
   var folder = 'folder1';
   $(".selected-car").attr('src',"img/folder1/pic1.jpeg");
   return false;
 });
 $('.folder2').click(function(){
   var folder = 'folder2';
   $(".selected-car").attr('src',"img/folder2/pic1.jpeg");
   alert(model); 
   return false;
 });
 $('.folder3').click(function(){
   var folder = 'folder3';
   $(".selected-car").attr('src',"img/folder3/pic1.jpeg");
   return false;
 });
 $('.folder4').click(function(){
   var folder = 'folder4';
   $(".selected-car").attr('src',"img/folder4/pic1.jpeg");
   return false;
 });
});


//COLOURS

$(function() {


     $('.colour1').click(function(){
       $(".selected-car").attr('src',"img/"+folder+"/cooper1.jpeg");
       return false;
     });
     $('.colour2').click(function(){
       $(".selected-car").attr('src',"img/"+folder+"/cooper2.jpeg");
       return false;
     });

});
```

html...

```
                 <div class="select-model">

                        <button class="folder1">model 1</button>
                        <button class="folder2">model 2</button>
                        <button class="folder3">model 3</button>
                        <button class="folder4">model 4</button>

                    </div>

                    <div class="configuration clearfix">

                        <img src="img/folder1/pic6.jpeg" class="selected-car"><!-- default pic -->

                        <div class="select-colour clearfix">
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/colour/colour1.jpeg" class="colour1"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/colour/colour2.jpeg" class="colour2"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/colour/colour3.jpeg" class="colour3"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/colour/colour4.jpeg" class="colour4"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/colour/colour5.jpeg" class="colour5"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/colour/colour6.jpeg" class="colour6"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/colour/colour7.jpeg" class="colour7"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/colour/colour8.jpeg" class="colour8"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/colour/colour9.jpeg" class="colour9"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/colour/colour10.jpeg" class="colour10"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: And the problem/question you have is...?

Comment: sorry... My problem is that when i choose a colour the variable is not passed into the path and the right path assign to the image src.

Comment: Where is your folder variable ever assigned a value?

Comment: Could this work in hand with a VBS script?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change 'modal' variable name to 'folder'.
turn these :

```
var model = 'folder1';
var model = 'folder2';
var model = 'folder3';
var model = 'folder4';
```

to these :

```
var folder = 'folder1';
var folder = 'folder2';
var folder = 'folder3';
var folder = 'folder4';
```

Comment: sorry i already did that in my code i just for to edit this script properly

Comment: i've edit code above, thanks for spotting. SO with the code like this it currently doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It's all about variable scope, you must remove variable definition for folder variable: becuase this definition changes it scope,
remover 'var' text and write these:

```
folder = 'folder1';
folder = 'folder2';
folder = 'folder3';
folder = 'folder4';
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the 'var' from within each onclick event...

```
        folder = 'folder1';
```

fixed :)